# Web services in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel

I have created my API for logging users into my application, but then it responds with the else part as the response

> {"error":true,"message":"Check your username or password"}

below is my controller

```
public function getLogin()
{
    $user = array(
            'username' => Input::get('username'),
            'password' => Input::get('password')
        );

      if (Auth::attempt($user))
         {
            $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
            $role = $user->roles;
                if ($role[0]->name == 'Customer')
                {
                   return Response::json(['error' => false, 'message' => 'Customer Logged in successfully', "user"=>$user]);
                }
                else
                 {
                  return Response::json(['error'=>true, 'message'=>'Check your login details']);
                 }

         }
      else
        {
            return Response::json(['error' => true, 'message' => 'Check your username or password']);
        }
}
```

Comment: please clear more your question.

Comment: What it is in $user variable? Is it array with username and password?